# Computer browsing not working

Tags: windows, domain, controller

We have multiple computers joined in domain. We also have domain controller (Windows server 2008 Enterprise).

The problem is, that sometimes computer browsing (Windows Explorer: My Network Places/Entire Network/MS Windows Network) works and sometimes doesn't.

Restarting Computer browser on domain controller helps poorly - usually not.

If users type other computer's name like Start/run: 
`\\computer1`
computer is accessible.

What seems to be the problem?

---

We already have WINS server installed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have (AD integrated) DNS running?

Comment: What do You mean exactly with (AD integrated) DNS? Service?

Comment: Active Directory integrated DNS.

Comment: No, that service is not running - it's not even in services.msc.

Comment: Well, we use AD integrated DNS and never have a problem. Not sure if it's the only or best way, but it works for us.

Comment: Where can we get that?

Comment: You can add it as a server role, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283014%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Add it as a server role on domain controller? How does it work then, when it's added? Then we must disable comoputer browser service?

Comment: We have AD integrated DNS (Forward Lookup Zones/Properties/Type).

Comment: you have the WINS server role installed but is it configured? Are your clients using the WINS server?

Answer (score 4):

DNS doesn't facilitate network browsing. NetBIOS facilitates network browsing.

Network browsing has never been "reliable" in the sense that the list of computers is always accurate and complete.

If you want to have an accurate and complete list of computers while browsing the network then you'll have to implement a WINS server.

Personally, I don't understand why this is an issue. Why is it important that users be able to browse an accurate and complete list of computers on the network? Do they not know where resources are (shared folders and printers) and need to browse the network to find them? If so, that's poor infrastructure design and management, IMO.

Comment: +1, I just want to note, that network browsing is working only on current IP broadcast, so at most 255 computers are shown (until you use WINS or enable broadcast traffic over subnets on switches)